# how to update many to many EF code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two models:

```
public class Exchanger : BaseContract
{
    [DataMember, Key, Column(TypeName = "bigint")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

     ....
    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<PaymentSystem> PaymentSystems { get; set; }

}

 [DataContract, Serializable]
 public class PaymentSystem : BaseContract
 {
    [Key, Column(TypeName = "bigint"), DataMember]
    public long Id { get; set; }

     ...

    [DataMember, JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Exchanger> ExchangersSupport { get; set; }

}
```

and fluent api directions to have many to many relations:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Exchanger>()
     .HasMany(t => t.PaymentSystems)
     .WithMany(t => t.ExchangersSupport)
     .Map(m => m.ToTable("ExchangerToPaymentSystem"));
```

code for inserting:

```
  public void Create(Exchanger ex, long clientId)
       {
         if (_context != null)
        {
             ex.ClientId = clientId;
             ex.LastTimeUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow;
             _context.Exchangers.Add(ex);
             _context.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
```

When I'm inserting new entry in Exchanger table EF create entries in ExchangerToPaymentSystem table, also it creates same entries in PaymentSystem table at the same time.
When i'm updating, nothing happens.
what am i do wrong?

Comment: post code for insert please.

Comment: can you write it in original post?

Comment: i can't see code for inserting to ExchangerToPaymentSystem  table.

Comment: Are you sure nothing is happening to Exhanger before Create gets called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I didn't knew that I had to reattach PaymentSystems collection to Object Context, it's not automaticaly be reattached, but marked as new (state = added).

```
 public void Create(Exchanger ex, long clientId)
    {
        if (_context != null)
        {
            ex.ClientId = clientId;
            ex.LastTimeUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow;

           **var ps = ex.PaymentSystems.Select(x=>x.Id);
            var ps2 = _context.PaymentSystems.Where(x => ps.Any(y => y == x.Id)).ToList();
            ex.PaymentSystems.Clear();
            foreach (var pp in ps2)
            {
                ex.PaymentSystems.Add(pp);
            }**

            _context.Exchangers.Add(ex);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you'r mapping configuration have to be something like following for middle table:

```
this.ToTable("ExchangerToPaymentSystem");
            this.HasKey(e => e.Id);

            this.HasRequired(e => e.Exchanger )
                .WithMany(e => e.ExchangersSupport )
                .HasForeignKey(pc => pc.ExchangerId);


            this.HasRequired(pc => pc.PaymentSystem )
                .WithMany(p => p.PaymentSystems)
                .HasForeignKey(pc => pc.PaymentSystemId);
```

often this behavior happens when you'r entities come from different data context.make sure that all the entities is from same data context.

Answer (score 0):

So, when you do

var exchanger = new Exchanger() { PaymentSystems = paymentSystems, ... };

it will automatically create the records in the link table for you, this is expecteds and required.
I'm not entirely sure I understand what the problem is now...